Sum of squares in family of q-polynomials
Let $[c]_q:=\frac{1-q^c}{1-q}=1+q+\cdots+q^{c-1}$ denote the $q$-analogue of the positive integer $c$. For a fixed $r\in\mathbb{N}$, let's write $\vec{c}:=(c_1,\dots,c_r)$ and
$\vec{n}:=(n_1,\cdots,n_r)$ including the scalar product $\vec{c}\cdot \vec{n}
=c_1n_1+\cdots c_rn_r$.
Consider now the polynomials and the corresponding coefficients
$$[c_1+1]_q^{n_1}\cdots [c_r+1]_q^{n_r}
:=\sum_{k=0}^{\vec{c}\cdot\vec{n}}\alpha_{\vec{c},\vec{n}}(k) q^k.$$

QUESTION. Is this true?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\vec{c}\cdot\vec{n}} (\alpha_{\vec{c},\vec{n}}(k))^2
=\alpha_{\vec{c},2\vec{n}}(\vec{c}\cdot\vec{n}).$$


For any polynomial $P(q)=\sum a_iq^i$, we have that $\sum a_i^2$ is the constant term of the Laurent polynomial $P(q)P(q^{-1})$. An affirmative answer follows easily.
